# Magento customers associated to website "Admin"

Tags: magento

What is the purpose of having a customer Associated to Website "admin" in magento instead of the normal default website, etc?  I cant seem to find the logic of why that exists.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is only based on where the customer was created. The weird thing is I know if you do something like a forgot password attempt on one website but your account was associated to another it will redirect you to the other one. I assume if the store id is 0 it will just redirect you the the current one.

Comment: It doesnt make sense to have a customer created in magento admin and then not let that user log in?  Seems almost pointless.